# Is there access log or metadata for Azure Data Catalog

Tags: azure, azure-data-catalog

Is there a way to access the metadata of Azure Data Catalog?  I looked up the documentation and went through the Azure Activity log of Azure Data Catalog.  However, it seems like there is no access activities(i.e. who accessed Azure Data Catalog at what point of time) log I can use.  Is there such activity anywhere in Azure at the moment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no such way to check the activity logs. I would recommend you to please have a look at [Azure Purview](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/purview/overview)  which has updated Data Catalog features.

You can refer to this document which has describes how to configure metrics, alerts, and diagnostic settings for Azure Purview using Azure Monitor: [Azure Purview metrics in Azure Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/purview/how-to-monitor-with-azure-monitor)